# Parse.Query("_User") vs Parse.Query("User") vs Parse.Query(Parse.User)

Tags: parse-platform

It seems as though

```
Parse.Query("_User")
```

is canonical, but `Parse.Query("User")` and `Parse.Query(Parse.User)` work too. Are there differences in behaviour between these? Any reason besides consistency to stick to one over the other?

`Parse.User` seems nicest, since it doesn't rely on a string literal, but it's not what I've seen in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Parse.Query(Parse.User)` is the preferred method, the actual class name for the internal User/Role/Installation classes are _User/_Role/_Installation, so you can use them.

Using `Parse.Query("User")` will not actually query the internal User class, and will instead look for your own User class. You can try by creating a new User object using "User" as the class name, and you'll see two User classes in your Data Browser, one with the special icon and one without.

Comment: Thanks! Although interestingly my code *was* doing User queries successfully when I just specified "User". (Since I don't have my own class called "User", in which case we'd see the behaviour you describe.)

Comment: @buildsucceeded if you did a query against the "User" class you would get back empty results, that's the designed functionality when doing a query against a class that doesn't exist.