# Parse Cloud Code on Heroku: beforeSave error

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I migrated my Parse application to be hosted on Heroku instead so I can use NPM modules. One of the problems I have is I seem to have a problem with before save:

```
console.log('register b4 save', Parse.User);
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(req, res) {
  console.log('in b4 save');
  res.success(req.object);
});
```

I get an error immediately after the 1st `console.log`:

> `class name cannot be empty`

Whats wrong?

Comment: Try _User for the name of class

Comment: Parse.User should be fine, no?

Comment: yeah it should be.. However, there is a class name missing and sometimes the idiom in JS for 'User' is to call it _User...

Comment: @RobertRowntree, thanks that works. Looks like Parse+Heroku is still very undocumented. `Parse.User` works on Parse but not Parse+Heroku. You could add it as an answer so I can mark it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060209/parse-query-user-vs-parse-queryuser-vs-parse-queryparse-user) the idiom on User is with the _ 'underscore' prefix.

Since your alert is asking about a missing class name , why not try using

**"_User"** in your first arg to 'beforeSave()'